# Trying to send geoJSON file to iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, geojson

I'm trying to upload the "Routing App Coverage File" to iTunesConnect. I get the message "Your file couldnt be saved, try again or contact us".

The file contents are below.. I've checked the contents on [geojsonlint](http://geojsonlint.com) and they seem correct.

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon", 
  "coordinates": [ 
    [[ [-75.767212,39.702961],
    [-76.25061,36.85545],
    [-78.491821,38.030786],
    [-78.200684,39.187562],
    [-77.774963,39.626846],
    [-75.767212,39.702961]
    ] ]]
}
```

Does the filename have to be special? Is there another problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help others. What solved this for me, was simply, that I had a couple of extra spaces, one at the beginning, and another at the end.